# Flash project does not show text correctly

Tags: flash-cs5

Currently I am working on fixing a 3 year old flash project. I am using Flash professional CS5. The problem is that text is not shown correctly; characters seem to be omitted in textfields.

- "Hoi welkom bij deze groep" is shown as "oi elkom bij deze groep".
- "MEIJUH" is shown as "gi"
- "De connectie met de server is verbroken" is shown as "e connectie met de serer is erbroken"

Note that these strings are in Dutch, but I don't think this is a problem for encoding. Above strings are "hardcoded" (or whatever you call it) in the project.

I think that 3 years ago the project was initially created in an earlier version of Adobe CS.

What might be a solution to fixing the correct showing of text in textfields?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this. I needed to embed all styles (not only Regular).

I did this under Text | Font Embedding...